# Eclipse keeps creating eclipse\.eclipseextension\feature folder in my Download folder on startup

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I don't know what happend, but when I recently installed Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) on my new PC, whenever I start it, it creates an empty folder structure in my Download folder, and I can't seem to find anything in the settings to dissable this. Anyone know what caused it, and how to remove it?

The exact path is:
"...\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse.eclipseextension\features"

Answer (score 5):

Apparently in the p2 directory are 2 files (`pool.info` and `profiles.info`) which refer to the *first use* path.

Deleting those 2 file put a stop to the issue for me.

Since I don't know what they are meant for, I can't really advise you to delete them, I can only say it worked for me.

Comment: I also deleted them. When I started Eclipse again, they were recreated, but now pointed to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the eclipse folder, find p2 directory where the (pool.info and profiles.info).

I just opened them with notepad and edit the path to match my eclipse folder path. Will need to use a little common sense, so gear up your thinking cap.

That fixed the problem for me. Ran eclipse and closed out with no problem.